# General questions about SQL Server in Microsoft VIsual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I would like to start learning about SQL Server projects development, I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 which includes some tools for SQL Server development. However it seems to me that some of the features found in SQL Server Express are not supported in Microsoft Visual Studio.

For example when I create a new view in Visual Studio SQL objects explorer there is no option to open a view designer, the only way I can create a view is by typing SQL instruction, i.e. there is no GUI for that purpose, although my studying materials indicate that there should be a view designer GUI.

[No option to open a view in design mode, most of the buttons are grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yxpd.png)

Also the commands for view, query and table design are always grayed out. Why?

Should I switch to SQL Server 2016 Express if I want to focus on learning about SQL or Microsoft Visual Studio offers the same functions and I simply can't find them?

Thank you.

Comment: I vote for _SQL Express 2016_ if you want to focus on SQL only, or even you can download _SQL Server Management Studio_, which is a tool for manage SQL sever.

Comment: usually you dont do the db design in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Data related work i always used MS SQL Server and if you want to study SQL Server then you should also do practice on SQL Server because somewhere i read that VS studio does not support "Script AS" kind of thing.
For you specific query for view creation there is GUI in SQL Server for VIEW creation where you can select required tables and functions to be used in your VIEW.